# Ruby-on-Rails renamed variables tests still see former names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rename, bcrypt

In order to have friendlier names to my column, I ran the following migration :

```
class RenameDigestColumnsOnUserToEncryptedTokens < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    rename_column :users, :password_digest, :encrypted_password
    rename_column :users, :activation_digest, :encrypted_activation_token
    rename_column :users, :reset_digest, :encrypted_reset_password_token
  end
end
```

It worked well, the columns are effectively renamed in my database.

I renamed accordingly all the actions I could have with these names, which means I don't have anything remaining in my code with whether Password_digest, activation_digest or reset_digest.

The problem is when I run the tests, I still get the errors as if I hadn't renamed them in the project, e.g. this kind of errors :

```
.E

Error:
PasswordResetsTest#test_password_resets:
NoMethodError: undefined method `password_digest' for #<User:0x00563d149684d8>
Did you mean?  password
    app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:29:in `update'
    test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'


bin/rails test test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:10
```

The code of the password_resets_controller's update action is what follows :

```
def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty?
      @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      # to prevent, on a public machine for example, people from pressing the back button and changing
      # the password (and getting logged in to the site) whereas it's always been reset
      @user.update_attribute(:encrypted_reset_password_token, nil)
      flash[:success] = 'Password has been reset.'
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

And the related log_in method :

```
# Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
```

I tried restarting spring and even rebooting the computer, I can't see where it comes from, how the computer can still see these names.

I am using the bcrypt gem to generate encrypted tokens, formerly named with digest, and this is those ones I tried to rename.

Has anyone ever had this problem ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you run your migration in the test environment?

`bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: Yes I did, I even reset the development database, and my application has the same problem as the tests, it looks for the previous names, so it's not working anymore.

Comment: Can you post `password_resets_controller.rb` update action ?

Comment: I edited the question :)

Comment: which line is line 29 on password_resets_controller.rb:29 ?

Comment: It is the elsif line, but I found the problem, I uncommented the has_secure_password in the model, and this require password_digest to work. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see an error about password_digest column maybe you are using Active record *has_secure_password* which requires that column: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Actually, I removed devise from my project to create my own authentication system, and it worked well until this renaming...

Comment: Same thing, I removed has_secure_password to build it on my own and customize it :)

Comment: Hmm just found out that I reactivated it I don't know how, so that was the cause of the problem, thank you for your help :)